# How to write identical information in a specific cell for all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with around 50 sheets where I've inserted a row at the beginning of the data. Now I want to write the variables names. For example: In cell `A1` I want to write *"code"* , in `B1` I wanna write *"price"*, and so on till `F1`.

I want to do this simultaneously for all the Excel sheets.

*I tried with this code:*

```
Sub mycode()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("A1") = "code"
    Range("B1") = "denom"
    Range("C1") = "location"
    Range("D1") = "area_m2"
    Range("E1") = "price_$m2"
    Range("F1") = "zoning"
Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get only the variables names on my active sheet.
I want the names for all the sheets of my workbook.

Could you please suggest some modifications for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please understand that we cannot provide code and that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: In your original code, you need to use `ws` within the loop.

Comment: `ws.Range("A1") = "code"` and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Alternative procedure**

I'd like to demonstrate an alternative to @BigBen 's valid answer using the `FillAcrossSheets` method:

```
Sub FillHeaders(rng As Range, arr)
    rng = arr: Sheets.FillAcrossSheets rng
End Sub
```

**Example call**

```
FillHeaders Sheet1.Range("A1:F1"), Array("code", "price", "foo", "bar", "test2", "test3")
```

**Clarifying notes to the `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets` method**
//--- Edit as of 03/13 2024

- a) The **`Sheets`** property of the Workbook object without any further indications returns a collection of **all the sheets** in the specified or active workbook: `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets rng`
- b) One can limit the collection to fewer sheets by subreferencing an array of sheet names (or index numbers): `Sheets(SheetsArr).FillAcrossSheets rng`, where SheetsArr might comprise e.g. `SheetsArray = Split("Sheet1 Sheet3 Sheet4")` or even `..= Array(1,3,4)`. - *In this case it is important to *include* the sheet containing the base range `rng`to avoid a runtime error 1004.*
- c) Surprisingly one may even pass an *empty SheetsArray*: `Sheets(Array()).FillAcrossSheets rng` with the same result as `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets rng` alone.
- d) The `Sheets.FillAcrossSheets` method comprises a further argument `Type` which can be used for the formatting purposes discribed below.

**VBA language reference**

> **Syntax:** {Sheets object}`.FillAcrossSheets Range[, Type]`

- [Sheets.FillacrossSheets method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.fillacrosssheets)
- [Type argument: xlFillWith Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfillwith)

| Name (Type arg.) | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlFillWithAll | -4104 | Copy contents and formats. |
| xlFillWithContents | 2 | Copy contents only. |
| xlFillWithFormats | -4122 | Copy formats only. |

Answer (score 4):

Only answering because this piqued my curiosity:

```
Sub Test()
    Sheets.Select
    Range("A1:F1").Select
    Selection.Value = Array("code", "price", "foo", "bar", "test2", "test3")
End Sub
```

Note that `Select`ing is usually discouraged, but seemed to be necessary (though [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884112/9245853)) in this case to avoid looping and write the values to all the sheets at once.

Comment: Ooh, it's always neat to see an exception and actually require the use of `.Select`.

Comment: @BruceWayne agreed. And it even works if there are chart sheets.

Comment: Like your interesting hints regarding the use of `.Select` +1 :-) ; posted an alternative method FYI - @BigBen

Comment: `.Select` is not evil if one knows how to handle it :)

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution. This is it:

```
 Sub mycode()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Range("A1:F1").Value = Array("code", "denom", "location", "area_m2", "price_$m2", "zoning_use")
Next ws

End Sub
```

I hope it helps

Comment: @BigBen You're right I forgot to type ws. Your solution is quite better.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything wrong with the looping, as far as it is not activating the sheet, it is really fast and not visible:

```
Sub TestCode()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("A1") = "code"
            .Range("B1") = "denom"
            .Range("C1") = "location"
            .Range("D1") = "area_m2"
            .Range("E1") = "price_$m2"
            .Range("F1") = "zoning"
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```