# Set range to current values and current formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am trying to cycle through multiple sheets in a work book and replace the formulas with values.

I would like to retain any formatting in the cells though (e.g. when I run this, it will not only change 3% to .03, but preserve any formatting)

Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
Sub copypastfa()

Dim count As Integer
For count = 1 To 9

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z101")
 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.count, rng.Columns.count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select

Next count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two unconvential approaches (other than copying)**

As you found out yourself, assigning (datafield) arrays to target ranges transport only values.

**[0) The conventional way]**

A *familiar* way to solve the asked requirement to include all formats would consist in subsequent copying/pasting formats as well as values as follows:

```
Sub TheConventionalWay()
'0) get worksheets collection
    Dim w   As Sheets               ' use the wider declaration type here and 
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' assign only worksheets to the sheets collection
'1) define source range 
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = w(1).Range("A1:Z101")
'2) Copy-Paste    
    rng.Copy                
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 to 9
      With Worksheets(i).Range(rng.Address)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next
End Sub
```

> ... but I would also like to demonstrate **two** *not so well-known* **quick approaches** here:

**Approach 1) via xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet**

This approach allows to get the complete spreadsheet info in an XML string which can be reassigned to the size identical target ranges. Furthermore it needs no double-assignements.

```
Sub XMLSpreadsheetApproach()
'0) get worksheets collection
    Dim w   As Sheets               ' use the wider declaration type here and 
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' assign only worksheets to the sheets collection
'1) define source range 
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = w(1).Range("A1:Z101")
    rng.Value2 = rng.Value2         ' change formulae to values
'2) Get Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet), aka Value(11)
    Dim Val11 as string: Val11 = rng.Value(11)
'3) Pass full XML Spreadsheet info to following worksheets    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 to 9          ' suffices to start at 2
      Worksheets(i).Range(rng.Address).Value(11) = Val11    ' xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet = 11
    Next
End Sub
```

**Syntax**

> [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) *(RangeValueDataType)*

where *[RangeValueDataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)* `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet` - equalling **`11`** - returns the values, **formatting**, formulas, and names of the specified Range object in the XML Spreadsheet format.

---

**Approach 2) via `FillAcrossSheets` method**

The widely unknown [`FillAcrossSheets` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.fillacrosssheets) copies a range to the same area on all other worksheets in a collection.

**Syntax**

> .FillAcrossSheets (Range, Type)

where Type (i.e. the XlFillWith enumeration) distinguishes between

- -4104 .. `xlFillWithAll` copies contents and formats.
- 2 ........... `xlFillWithContents` copies contents only.
- -4122 .. `xlFillWithFormats` copies formats only.

```
Sub FillAcrossSheetsApproach()
'0) get worksheets collection
    Dim w   As Sheets               ' use the wider declaration type here and 
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' assign only worksheets to the sheets collection
'1) define source range 
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = w(1).Range("A1:Z101")
    rng.Value2 = rng.Value2         ' change formulae to values
'2) apply to ALL sheets
    w.FillAcrossSheets rng, xlFillWithAll
End Sub
```

If, however you want to include only a series of sheets, include the help function `GetWNames()` below and replace section 2) by:

```
'2a) apply ONLY to sheets 1 to 9    ' source sheet has to be included!
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(GetWNames(w,1,9)).FillAcrossSheets rng, xlFillWithAll
```

```
Function GetWNames(w As Sheets, first As Long, last As Long)
    Dim tmp() As String: ReDim tmp(first To last)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = first To last
        tmp(i) = w(i).Name
    Next i
    GetWNames = tmp             ' return Array(w(1).Name, .. w(last).Name)
    'Debug.Print Join(GetWNames, "|")
End Function
```

*Further link*

In an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879621/how-to-write-identical-information-in-a-specific-cell-for-all-sheets/58884112#58884112) I demonstrated how to write an array as identical information to all sheets using this method.

Comment: @RBRN1231 Might I ask you for feedback since I've invested some time in answering an older question of yours: did you find my post offering three different approaches helpful? - if so, consider to accept it by ticking the green checkmark and/or to upvote by clicking the up-arrow thus giving positive orientation to other contributors, too.