# Making the same increasing number appear in every sheet of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a reference number that increases every time I open the workbook. But how do I make it appear in every sheet in the same cell?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Range("I6").Value = Range("I6"). Value + 1
End sub
```

That is my current code but I don't know how to reference the same cell in multiple sheets.

Comment: Do you know how to loop over worksheets?

Comment: No, i'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes there are very easy solutions, like here:

```
Sub test()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets:
  ws.Range("I6").Value = ws.Range("I6").Value + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way (*Just for fun*) which doesn't require a loop.

```
Sub Sample()
    Worksheets.Select
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    Sheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Having said that, you need to take care of few things before you use `.Activate` and `.Select`. For example, all the sheets must be visible and `Range("I6")` should be selectable.

Having said that I would recommend going with @Dominique answer.

Interesting read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Reminded me of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884112, which also doesn't require a loop.

Comment: @BigBen Aha! Lot of fun things that you can do in VBA. :)