How to copy a range to several worksheets by using a list of worksheets to copy to
VBA novice here. I have a complex spreadsheet but I’ll simplify it for my question. Let’s say I have a workbook with 20 worksheets.  Each worksheet has a three-letter name such as ABC. In the first worksheet is a range called CITIES in cells A1:A10. Each cell in CITIES has the name of a city. Also in the first worksheet in cells B1:B10 is a list of 10 of the worksheet names. I change this list periodically. I need a macro to copy the range CITIES into cell C1 of each worksheet listed in B1:B10.
With my macro (shown below), I have to change the worksheet names in the macro each time I make a change in the B1:B10 list. I want the macro to use the B1:B10 list to determine which worksheets to copy to.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
Sub CITIES_COPY ()
    Range("CITIES").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWX", "YZA", "BCD")). _
        Select
    Sheets("ABC").Activate
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub


My example below shows a few things that can help, especiallly when you're just starting out with VBA.

Use descriptive names for your variables and be as absolutely clear as you can.
You don't have to use Select to copy/paste. Just copy range to range.
I threw in a function to check the spelling of the worksheet, because that can certainly trip you up when trying to debug.

Option Explicit

Sub CopyCitiesToSheets()
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Sheet")
    
    Dim cities As Range
    Set cities = srcWS.Range("CITIES")
    
    '--- does not assume that you have the same number of rows
    Dim destSheetNames As Range
    With srcWS
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("CITIES").Offset(0, 1).Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set destSheetNames = srcWS.Range("CITIES").Offset(0, 1).Resize(lastRow, 1)
    End With
    
    Dim destSheetName As Variant
    For Each destSheetName In destSheetNames
        '--- establish where the cities are going, but sure to match the same
        '    size and shape of the source range
        Dim destination As Range
        Set destination = GetDestinationRange(destSheetName, cities.Rows.Count, cities.Columns.Count)
        destination.Value = cities.Value
    Next destSheetName
    
End Sub

Function GetDestinationRange(ByVal destSheetName As String, _
                             ByVal numRows As Long, _
                             ByVal numCols As Long) As Range
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dstWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(destSheetName)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "ERROR: not a value worksheet name!  Did you misspell it?", _
               Buttons:=vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
               Title:="ERROR in Worksheet Name"
    End If
    Set GetDestinationRange = dstWS.Range("C1").Resize(numRows, numCols)
End Function


Thanks PeterT.  I didn't try your solution because my problem was already solved by Black cat and BigBen.  However, I really appreciate your response and tips on coding.

Nicely done +:); fyi posted an alternative solution via Excel method FillAcrossSheets you might be interested in.

Place this code into the first sheet code module (where the data are)
The ranges are hardcoded so this must keep in mind. E.g. if the sheets are less then 10 there will be an error of the missing names, and if greater then 10 the sheets over 10 are left out. "A1:A10" can change to the named range.
Sub mulcopy()

Range("A1:A10").Copy
For i = 1 To 10
  shnames = Cells(i, "B")
  Application.Worksheets(shnames).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Next i


End Sub



Many thanks.  However, I get an error message that says "Compile error:  Variable not defined" and the I is highlighted.  Please advise.

Dim i As Long, Dim shnames As String

Thanks BigBen.  Now it works perfectly!

Thanks Black cat.  With BigBen's tweak, it's working perfectly!

If you use Option Explicit in the module then every variable has to be declared. Like @BigBen commented.

Late post demonstrating the little-known method FillAcrossSheets.
It copies

a given range in Sheet1 (e.g. cells A1:A10)
into a given target range (e.g. cells C1:C10)
into all worksheets predefined in adjacent cells (here: B1:B10):

Example call
Option Explicit               ' (code module head)

Sub ExampleCall()
'0) base definitions
    With Sheet1.Range("CITIES")       ' << Change sheet reference as needed
        Dim cities:   cities = .Value2
        Dim mySheets: mySheets = getSheets(.Offset(0, 1))
        If UBound(mySheets) = -1 Then Exit Sub
    End With
'1) set target range in first sheet of chosen worksheets
    Dim tgtRng As Range
    Set tgtRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheets(1)).Range("C1").Resize(UBound(cities), 1)
'2) write cities to target range in chosen worksheets
    FillSheets tgtRng, cities, mySheets    ' << main procedure FillSheets
End Sub

Main procedure FillSheets
Sub FillSheets(rng As Range, data, Optional SheetsArr)
'Purp: write data to all sheets included in argument SheetsArr
'Note: c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879621/how-to-write-identical-information-in-a-specific-cell-for-all-sheets/58884112#58884112
'      c.f. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.fillacrosssheets
'a) fill the range in the first target sheet
    rng = data
'b) write data via Excel method FillAcrossSheets
    If IsMissing(SheetsArr) Then    ' fill all sheets
        Sheets().FillAcrossSheets rng
    Else                            ' fill only target sheets
        If UBound(SheetsArr) - LBound(SheetsArr) Then
            Sheets(SheetsArr).FillAcrossSheets rng
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Helper function getSheets (vs. MS365)
Function getSheets(rng As Range)
'Purp:  assign sheet names to 1D array ignoring empty cells
'Note:  needs vers. MS365 !
    Dim addr As String: addr = rng.Address(external:=True)
    getSheets = Evaluate("Transpose(Filter(" & addr & "," & addr & "<>0))")
End Function


GetSheets() for earlier versions
If you don't dispose of vers. MS 365 to get the sheet names, you may try the following code:
Function getSheets(rng As Range)
'Purp:  assign sheet names to 1D array and omit empty names
'a) assign values to 1D array
    Dim tmp: tmp = Application.Transpose(rng.Value2)
'b) omit empty sheet names
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(tmp)
        If Len(Trim(tmp(i))) Then
            ii = ii + 1: tmp(ii) = tmp(i)
        End If
    Next i
    If ii Then
        ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To ii)
    Else
        tmp = Array()
    End If
'c) return function result
    getSheets = tmp
End Function


